# Get SSH login name in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a Bash script on server **A** that finds the logged in SSH user via the `logname` command, even if it's run as `root` with `sudo`. If I SSH into server **A** from my desktop and run the script, it works fine.

However, I've set up a post-commit hook on SVN server **S** which SSH's into **A** and runs the script there, which causes logname to fail, with error "logname: no login name".

If I SSH into **S** from my desktop, then SSH into **A** from there, it works correctly, so the error must be in the fact that the SVN hook ultimately does not run from a virtual terminal.

What alternative to `logname` can I use here?

Comment: Third paragraph, "If I SSH into R": Did you mean into S?

Comment: [The man page](http://ss64.com/bash/logname.html) says that `logname` checks the login name from `/var/run/utmp`... Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `id` command:

```
  $ ssh 192.168.0.227 logname
  logname: no login name
```

However

```
  $ ssh 192.168.0.227 id
  uid=502(username) gid=100(users) groups=100(users)
```

In a bash script you can cut the username out of the id output with something like

```
  $ id | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f1
  username
```

To have a script that works both in a sudo environment and without a terminal you could always execute different commands conditionally.

```
if logname &> /dev/null ; then 
    NAME=$( logname )
else 
    NAME=$( id | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f1 )
fi
echo $NAME
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not have the cross-sudo property of `logname`, i.e. `ssh 192.168.0.277 sudo id` => `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: An `if` would work, but I'd prefer to do `if [ logname works ] else $SUDO_USER`, because $SUDO_USER does not survive two `sudo`s. Is there a `logname works` check possible?

Comment: Very strange. I have `if logname &> /dev/null; then
        echo has logname`. This outputs "has logname" \n "logname: no login name"

Comment: Never mind that, in my real script (not a quick test) the same construct suddenly works. Update: Found out why. The real script is `bash`, while the test script is `sh`.

Comment: Shorter version: `NAME=$(logname 2>&- || id -un)`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I ended up with.

```
if logname &> /dev/null; then
    human_user=$(logname)
else
    if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]; then
        human_user=$SUDO_USER
    else
        human_user=$(whoami)
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `id -nu`. No silly forking and cutting to get at the user name.

Comment: `sudo id -nu` prints `root`, so that's not useful.

Comment: Does `id -rnu` then print the real UID?